# Do PHP resources keep their state across pages?

Tags: php, resources, ldap

I store a resource link identifier (specifically an LDAP connection link) in a global variable and check in my first initialisation to create it only if it's not already in `$GLOBALS` array.

I bind to the LDAP connection with correct credentials when logging a user in, but when I later try to search LDAP directory, I realise that the connection has lost its state (from the fact that I can't do searches).

Is there a way of keeping an LDAP connection's state across pages? I can't store them in session variables as they can't be serialised.

Comment: does *later* mean in following requests?

Comment: yes, it does. it also means in a different page, but making sure it has been initialised.

Comment: the @downvoter, IF YOU DON'T HAVE THE COURAGE TO AT LEAST LEAVE A HELPFUL COMMENT, PLEASE DON'T DOWNVOTE IT. you don't think I've done some research before asking this? Or if you think it was answered somewhere else, then provide the link before voting down.

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not. Just like you always need to connect to the database each request, you'll need to create a new connection to LDAP too.

In essence: every request starts with a clean slate, you'll need to fetch resources, open connections each time.

Comment: it looks like that is the case, although I couldn't locate any documentation that would confirm this.

Comment: @mavili It's the nature of PHP that resources, variables etc are valid just for a single request. You need to understand the lifecycle of a (apache) php request: http://www.laruence.com/wp-content/uploads/the-php-life-cycle.pdf